# What is the standard term for a Jacobian that is a many to one mapping?

Tags: integration, multivariable-calculus

Normally, Jacobians are defined to be $1-1$ mappings. However, I was wondering if there was a Jacobian for many-to-one mappings. I've seen this briefly mentioned as an integral Jacobian in the past, but was not able to find more information. Does anyone know of such a method? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The derivative of a function does not have to be injective. Take $f:\mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$ defined by $x \mapsto 3^{-1}x^3$ then $d_xf = x^2$ which is not $1-1$. Does that answer your question? If you want more, take $f: \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}^2$ defined by $t \mapsto (\cos t, \sin t)$, this is a "many to one" mapping. It is the derivative of $g = (\sin t, \cos t)$. The Jacobian is just a linear map, in particular a map. The term you may be looking for is multi-valued function.